# How to download complete AWS CloudWatch log

Tags: logging, amazon-cloudwatch

**QUESTION SUMMARY**

How to download a complete log from CloudWatch using CLI tools?

The log that I download is incomplete. I know this because if I reverse the order, using `--start-from-head`, I get new content. Not just reversed-order.

---

**RESEARCH**

I am trying to trace a tricky intermittent failure in a (Flask/Zappa, AWS lambda) microservice.

I need to download the logs.

I can inspect the logs in CloudWatch:

Here's one containing the text I'm after:

[image]

However if I download this log, the downloaded file does *not* contain this text:

```
> aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name '/aws/lambda/api-dev' --log-stream-name '2018/12/01/[$LATEST]59bc7e539d7948688e0666f8ed14822a' > wtf.txt

> cat wtf.txt | grep "timer"
```

i.e. Nothing

Now if I add `--start-from-head`, now I see it:

```
> aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name '/aws/lambda/api-dev' --log-stream-name '2018/12/01/[$LATEST]59bc7e539d7948688e0666f8ed14822a' --start-from-head  > wtf.txt

> cat wtf.txt | grep "timer"
        "message": "> > >  starting game timer  < < <\n",
```

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/get-log-events.html I observe:

> --limit (integer)
>
> The maximum number of log events returned. If you don't specify a value, the maximum is as many log events as can fit in a response size of 1 MB, up to 10,000 log events.

... and:

```
> ls -l wtf.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 pi  staff  1247053  3 Dec 10:55:14 2018 wtf.txt
```

So it is going over 1MB. So it appears that the log is too long. The text I'm after is at the earliest period in the log.

So the question becomes: How to download the complete log?

I try setting a higher `--limit`, but get:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the GetLogEvents operation: 1 validation error detected: Value '999999' at 'limit' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have value less than or equal to 10000

And 10000 is the default!  And setting an arbitrary limit is ugly anyway. Whatever I set there is a risk that the log will be longer.

How about using the documented `"nextForwardToken"` key?

```
def get_complete_log(stream_name):
    nextForwardToken = None

    while True:
        param_group =  " --log-group-name '/aws/lambda/api-dev'"
        param_stream = " --log-stream-name '" + stream_name + "'"
        param_token = (" --next-token '" + nextForwardToken + "'") if nextForwardToken else ""

        params = param_group + param_stream + param_token

        cmd = "aws logs get-log-events" + params + " > logs/tmp.txt"
        print(cmd)
        system(cmd)      

        with open('logs/tmp.txt','r') as f:
            tmp = f.read()

            print('CONTENTS:', tmp[:120], '\n')

            J = json.loads( tmp )

        nextForwardToken = J.get("nextForwardToken")

        if not nextForwardToken:
            break


get_complete_log( "2018/12/01/[$LATEST]59bc7e539d7948688e0666f8ed14822a" )
```

And if I inspect the output:

```
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name '/aws/lambda/api-dev' --log-stream-name '2018/12/01/[$LATEST]030c7bd5c6ff4d9eb3bb56b8607746b8' > logs/tmp.txt
CONTENTS: {
    "events": [
        {
            "timestamp": 1543707627572,
            "message": "START RequestId: 7b34fa3b-f5 

aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name '/aws/lambda/api-dev' --log-stream-name '2018/12/01/[$LATEST]030c7bd5c6ff4d9eb3bb56b8607746b8' --next-token 'f/34426362085021867195594556764906427633106607331166978053' > logs/tmp.txt
CONTENTS: {
    "events": [],
    "nextForwardToken": "f/34426362085021867195594556764906427633106607331166978053",
    "nextBackw
```

So everything except the first call returns `"events": []` and `"nextForwardToken":` is the same token that was passed in!

Comment: From my experience, searching for logs in CloudWatch is terribly unreliable (especially if you use the AWS console). However, I've been very successful using this [CLI tool](https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs). It's extremely simple and  seems to fetch all of the logs in the time-range I specify. You can also grep the output stream to find particular matches or just pipe it to a file.

Comment: @macalaca, if you would care to put this as an answer I will gladly accept it. While it does not explicitly go to the root of the AWS log CLI failure, it provides an alternative (and preferable) solution path. Thanks!

Comment: Try my script: https://gist.github.com/shankara-n/3573ee834ac0f3cb6d9d9abb35e1cd24

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would recommend trying out this [CLI tool](https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs). In my opinion, it's much more reliable than the AWS console and the AWS CLI tool. I've used it to search through massive log streams in CloudWatch. You can easily specify a time-range to search over or even grep over CloudWatch log streams. You can also look at a log stream in real-time. The example below searches over all the log streams in a group for the specified time-range (see also that I'm grepping for the pattern ERROR and outputting to a file and the console using `tee`):

```
awslogs get my_log_group ALL --start='23/1/2015 12:00' --end='23/1/2016 13:00' | grep ERROR | tee errlogs.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a very good tool. I wish the AWS CLI would incorporate it, or the `aws logs` would get a serious upgrade

Comment: In my experience, it's much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the whole log stream can be done with aws-cli as well. Using `aws logs filter-log-events` and `--start-time 0`(seems to be default) prints all logs from the start.

I've also added an optional `jq` command to extract only plain messages for convenience.

```bash
export LOG_GROUP="/aws/lambda/api-dev"
export LOG_STREAM="2018/12/01/[$LATEST]59bc7e539d7948688e0666f8ed14822a"
aws logs filter-log-events \
  --start-time 0 \
  --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP \
  --log-stream-name-prefix $LOG_STREAM \
  | jq -r '.events[].message' \
  > aws.log
```